# numpy on cluster via ssh

Tags: python, numpy, ssh, cluster-computing

For my studies I have to use a cluster to which I am logged on via SSH. I want to use a python script using numpy modules. Unfortunately the numpy version seems to be to old and doesn't include all needed modules. How can I get access to a newer numpy without sudo rights?

Comment: Install your modules in a virtual environment using pip (assuming the cluster machine has the dependencies to compile everything)

Answer (score 1):

If `pip` is installed on the cluster, then just install numpy under your home directory on the cluster:

```
pip install --user numpy
```

Comment: Ok I heard about pip, but I did not understand that it has to be installed on the cluster. Thank you! But unfortunately it's not installed.`-bash: pip: command not found`

Comment: Is `easy_install` installed on the system? If functions similarly (and takes the "--user" option). You could also follow @MrE's suggestion if `virtualenv` is installed on the system (i.e., call virtualenv to setup a new environment, then use the pip executable provided by virtualenv).